# Tramp/Emacs 27 freeze on Mac

Tags: tramp, mac

I'm facing a major issue with Tramp and Emacs 27.1 on a Mac (10.15.7), which makes it almost impossible to work on remote files ...

As soon as I start to type a SSH or SCP based URL in the mini buffer (after C-x C-f), I get a dialog from the OS, that I need to permit access to some keychain password. One of those trigger this issue:

```
/ssh:
/sshx:
/scp:
/-:
```

The dialog always asks for access to the oldest entry in my keychain, totally unrelated to what I do in emacs.

When I permit the access, I've still a chance to stop (ESC or C-g).
When I reject, the emacs freeze and I can only kill the app.

Any hint or recommendation is very appreciated.

Br,
Michael

PS: When I type the URL faster, or paste the full URL, I pass the issue sometimes and I can open remote files.

Comment: I don't know why you are asked for the keychan password. This needs more investigation, better you ask on the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` ML. Tramp blocking on macOS, however, has been reported several times last months. There are some fixes, some of them in Emacs 28, some of them in Tramp itself. For the latter fixes, you might try the recent Tramp 2.5.0.1 from GNU ELPA, whether it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hints ... I'll try them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints I've updated the bundled version of tramp (2.4) with the one from ELPA (2.5.0.1).

After this the problems were resolved in Emacs 27.1.

All URLs over SSH/SCP are working, on high and low latency networks, with and without SUDO.

Thanks for the support!